# Usage of templated interfaces cause “Undefined reference to”

Tags: c++, templates, generics, interface, compiler-errors

So I'm getting the following compile error :

```
CMakeFiles/moje.dir/src/main/cpp/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV10ReadWriterINSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_istringstreamIcS3_S4_EEE[_ZTV10ReadWriterINSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEENS0_19basic_istringstreamIcS3_S4_EEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `Writer<std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::write(std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
CMakeFiles/moje.dir/src/main/cpp/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV6WriterINSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE[_ZTV6WriterINSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `Writer<std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::write(std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
```

The implementation is as follows :

Writer.h

```
#ifndef WRITER_H
#define WRITER_H

template<typename T>
class Writer {
public:
    virtual ~Writer() {}
    virtual void write(T &in);
};
#endif /* WRITER_H */
```

Reader.h

```
#ifndef READER_H
#define READER_H

template<typename T>
class Reader {
public:
    virtual ~Reader() {}
    virtual T read();
};
#endif /* READER_H */
```

ReadWriter.h

```
#ifndef READWRITER_H
#define READWRITER_H
#include "Reader.h"
#include "Writer.h"

template<typename R, typename W>
class ReadWriter : public Reader<R>, public Writer<W>{
public:
    virtual ~ReadWriter() {}
};
#endif /* READWRITER_H */
```

ConfigReadWriter.h

```
#ifndef CONFIGREADWRITER_H
#define CONFIGREADWRITER_H
#include "header/ReadWriter.h"

class ConfigReadWriter : public ReadWriter<std::ostringstream, std::istringstream> {
public:
    ConfigReadWriter(Config &config) : config_(config) {}
    ~ConfigReadWriter() {}

    std::ostringstream read() override {
        std::ostringstream ss("ConfigReadWriter::read");
        return ss;
    };

    void write(std::istringstream& in) override {
        std::cout << "ConfigReadWriter::write" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    Config& config_;
};
#endif /* CONFIGREADWRITER_H */
```

Main.cpp :

```
#include "header/config/Config.h"
#include "header/config/ConfigReadWriter.h"


int main() {
    std::string a = "1";
    Config config(1, a);
    ConfigReadWriter rw(config);
    return 0; 
}
```

I understand that by keeping the implementation in the header i should not occur error with undefined reference.
Corrected the implementation in the write method to fit the interface.
Still tho have compile errors. Reading the link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: Agreed make sure you did not try to implement your templates in source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your implementation supplies `void write(std::istringstream)` methods taking a copy while undefined reference is for method taking a reference like `void write(std::istringstream &)` that you did not implement at base class `virtual void write(T &in);`. So you should update implementation with correct signature:

```
virtual void write(T &in) = 0; // no implementation
```

...

```
void write(std::istringstream &) override    {
    std::cout << "ConfigReadWriter::write" << std::endl;
}
```

`override` specifier ensures that method signature matches to the virtual method signature in base class.

Comment: I will use a specific override macro for my code base, but for snippet code I've used w/o it. Thx for that reference mistake, fixed but code still does not compile (updated fail compile information). Reading the links :)

Comment: Ok everything works, it required pure virtual function aside from that typo with reference.